# Batch approve comments

Tags: comments, spam, akismet

Akismet went crazy and sent several hundred comments to spam. Right now, I have to manually mark each comment as "Not Spam" and then manually move all of them from Pending to Approved. Any way to do this in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this SQL query to approve all spam comments:

```
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_approved = 1 WHERE comment_approved = 'spam';
```